# Wrapping text in grid column

Tags: atk4

I want the text in a column of a grid to wrap. The grid is created with a model. I have found the format_wrap-method, but it does not seem to do anything:

```
$grid->format_wrap('description');
```

What do I do wrong?
Thanks,
Jeppe

Answer (score 2):

Don't use such a methods directly.
This is only correct way to use formatters:

```
$grid->addFormatter('description','wrap');
```

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Grid/Basic.php#L237

Comment: you can also use type 'text'.

Comment: btw - i think we should refactor format_* as protected methods.

Comment: addFormatter or setFormatter?

Comment: read descriptions for these methods.
-- setFormatter :: Replace current formatter for field ||
 --addFormatter :: Add extra formatter to existing field